# How to add same column value but having different IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two SQL Server 2008R2 tables as below:

- `Tbl_Item` (`Item_Id`)
- `Tbl_Item_Cost` (`Item_Id, Item_Cost`)

Values in the tables are as below:

`Tbl_Item`:

```
Item_Id
--------------------
Candy  
Chocolate  
IceCream  
Chocolate/IceCream
```

`Tbl_Item_Cost`:

```
Item_Id      Item_Cost  
----------------------
Candy           10  
Chocolate       20  
IceCream        30
```

Now I want to display the Item and its cost. Only thing is cost for Chocolate/IceCream should be addition of Chocolate and IceCream i.e. 20+30=50. So the result should look like

```
Item_Id      Item_Cost  
-----------------------
Candy           10  
Chocolate       20  
IceCream        30  
IceCream/Chocolate  50
```

What can be the simplest way to do this in SQL Server 2008R2?

Comment: I think you need to change your design to incorporate a many-to-many approach. You are going to save yourself a world of hurt...

Comment: Actually I just need many to many approach for this one item. For rest all it's direct mapping. This one item needs to sum the cost of two different items..

Comment: There will be more, it's a rule. Besides even if you got clever a split the multi-value, you'll still have to check to see if Item_name has / in it every time, so there only being one at the moment doesn't help you t all.

Comment: @BI_DEV Can there be an Auto-Increment or identity column in table Tbl_Item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. As you don't have the option of changing the design, although it's not good to hardcode anything but if you really want this to occur for only(always) these two items, you may try this.

```
SELECT I.Item_Id,CASE WHEN I.Item_Id='Chocolate/IceCream' THEN (SELECT SUM(Item_Cost) FROM dbo.Tbl_Item_Cost WHERE Item_Id IN ('Chocolate','IceCream')) ELSE Item_Cost END AS Item_Cost
FROM dbo.Tbl_Item_Cost C
RIGHT JOIN dbo.Tbl_Item I ON I.Item_Id=C.Item_Id
```

RESULT:
[image]

If I am missing something then please let me know so that I can come with better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following:

```
SELECT t1.item_id+'/'+t2.item_id, t1.cost+t2.cost
FROM tbl_item_cost t1 INNER JOIN tbl_item_cost t2 ON t1.item_id<>t2.item_id
```

We could also use CROSS JOIN which allows us to get all possible pairs `(xn, yn)` from sets `X={x1, x2, ..., xn},  Y={y1, y2, ... , yn}`. Here `X=Y`. But then we would get pairs `(xi, xi)` - example: ice cream/ice cream.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to have an other table with combinations of items.
ie.

```
Products
ID Name
1  Chocolate And Icecream
2  Chocolate
3  Icecream

Items
ProductID SubItemId
1         1
1         2
2         1
3         2 

Sub_Items
1 Chocolate 20
2 Iceceam 30
```

Multi-column values such as Chocolate/Icecream as are a do not do this.

Your query would then be something like

```
Select p.Name, sum(s.cost)
From Products p
inner join items i on p.id = i.ProductID
inner join sub_Items s on i.SubItemId = s.Id
group by p.id
```

Comment: I think that is a great solution but unfortunately I don't have the flexibility of changing the design. The Costs are coming from a cube as a  result of MDX query. Can I do it with existing design? Can I use CASE here. Just a guess :)

Comment: There are other options, but they are all messy. Basically you have to split around slash and then do a sub query for each part of the item. Edit your question and say you can't do a proper design and need to split around slash in the name. looks like @user316298 has come up with an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have create a **`function Split()`**
2. You have to add an **`auto increment Id`** in table **`Tbl_Item`**

**`1.function Split()`**

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

**`2.Add column`**

```
Alter table Tbl_Item
Add Id Int Identity(1, 1)
```

Query:

```
select TI.Item_Id,t.Cost
from Tbl_Item TI
inner join (
            select T.ID,sum(TIC.[Item_Cost]) as Cost
            from (select Id,items
                    from Tbl_Item
                    cross apply dbo.split([Item_Id], '/'))t
            inner join Tbl_Item_Cost TIC on TIC.[Item_Id]=t.items
            group by T.ID
            )t on t.Id=TI.id
```

**[SQL Fiddle to test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4694/1)**